# Is there a way to automatically import functions from packages while writing an R package?

Tags: r, roxygen2

Say, I write a function for an R package where I use functions from another package:

```r
do_something <- function(path, agg_factor = 2) {
   x <- raster::raster(path)
   x <- raster::aggregate(x, fact = agg_factor)
   return(x)
}
```

I can easily import the `raster` and `aggregate` functions to the namespace by using `roxygen2`:

```r
#' @importFrom raster raster aggregate
```

If I have a long function, I can even find which functions I should import by running R CMD CHECK in Rstudio/`testthat` but is there a way to automatically add these functions into the `@importFrom` field or equivalent field that automatically adds them when `::` is used?

This would save a lot of time while writing large packages...

EDIT: as pointed out by @r2evans, @akrun, @user2554330 (see the comments), this was a stupid question. You need to do either `::` or `@importFrom` but not both. See, for example, [here](https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/depends.html). I will not delete the question since it provoked so much discussion. The moderators may if they want. It should probably be closed anyhow or someone can answer it clarifying my misunderstanding.

Comment: I think not. And to be clear, if you use `@importFrom`, you don't need `::`-notation (unless there are ambiguities in function names, as in `aggregate`). It does not harm to use `::` if you've already imported the functions, but it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You perhaps understand what I am after though? Using `::` in a long function and an option in `roxygen2` to import all `::` functions would save time over skimming through the entire function. Sure, I could import the entire package but many packages have ambiguous functions these days. Better to import only the functions I need.

Comment: @Mikko You could rename the functions once i.e. `aggregate_rast <- raster::aggregate` and then use that within the function

Comment: @akrun That sounds hacky. You do that?

Comment: I always specify the `::`, but there may be situations, where you may want to use ie.. an operator `%>%` etc.  I assume your issue is that you don't want to do `::` this multiple times.  In that case, a unique name function would work

Comment: I am happy always doing `::`. I am tired of finding all the `::`s from a long function and adding them to `@importFrom`, while forgetting a couple, running R CMD CHECK which takes 10 minutes and getting errors. I thought that automatization here would save time.

Comment: maybe something like this helps.  (NB not optimized or widely tested): `f = readLines('test.r'); f = gsub('.+ (.+::.+)\\(.+', '\\1',  f); f = f[grep('::', f)]`

Comment: I've used a shell-script before to find that, perhaps `sed -nE 's/.*\b([A-Za-z.]+::[^( ,]+).*/\1/pg' *.R | sort | uniq`. It can miss (if you have multiple `::`-calls on one line), but it's a reasonable start to find all imports in your files.

Comment: Importing a function is different from declaring that your package uses something from another package, and while that might be just a nuance, it can simplify your life. If you always use `::`-notation (which is good practice for many reasons, though certainly not absolute), then you just need to remember to add the particular package to the `DESCRIPTION` section for `Imports:`. You don't need to worry about importing each and every function individually.

Comment: @r2evans, you still need to add it in NAMESPACE. As an example, the raster package has similar function names to many other packages. I could use something like `@rawNamespace import(raster, except = shift)`. I read from somewhere, however, that it was the best practice to only import functions one needs to save clutter. I am aware that `::` is the standard and have no problem using it.

Comment: No, @r2evans is right.  If you're using `::`, you don't need anything in the `NAMESPACE` file.  You just need to name the package in `DESCRIPTION`.  However, a disadvantage is in debugging:  `step into` in the debugger will step into the `::` function first.  It's kind of irritating, so it's better to import the function, and then *not* to use `::`.

Comment: You don't need it in the `NAMESPACE`, though I used to think so as well. Some good reading for this; perhaps not doctrine, but the authors are well-informed (and respected): https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/depends.html and https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that. I think the checker on Rstudio warns about functions you forgot to import if you use `::`, no?

Comment: I don't use the RStudio IDE, sorry, just emacs/ess.

Comment: Hmm...one of those advanced ones ;) I am one of those who follow what Rstudio says :P

Comment: @user2554330 interesting point about the debugger and stepping into `::`, I hadn't noticed that difference. Without testing, I'm assuming that `@importFrom` and not using `::` might clear up the stack trace on errors, too, do you know if that's right?

Comment: Ok, I see. It's either `@importFrom` or `::`. So you are telling me that I have been doing redundant work all these years. It was worth the question, at least.